# Entity Framework 5 not installing correctly?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

I just installed VS 2012. I created a new project to do Code First with. I then used Nuget to add EF5 to the project, as per these instructions:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712906

I then verified it's install:
http://i1048.photobucket.com/albums/s361/usernames_r_stupid/Nuget_zpse7808c9b.png

Which shows that I have EF 5 installed. And indeed my App.config shows:

```
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```

But if I look at the properties of the System.Data.Entity assembly reference by my project it shows version 4.0.0.0!
http://i1048.photobucket.com/albums/s361/usernames_r_stupid/SystemDataProps_zps4a71be1b.png

What am I doing wrong here? This is driving me nuts.

~S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be looking to `EntityFramework.dll`. `System.Data` is not the EntityFrakework assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Nuget creates a packages folder with the above mentioned EntityFramework.dll. I manually referenced it,but it ended up telling me that it was already referenced. ONce I ran my project fo the first time it showed up in my references. Weird.  Was System.Data.Entity not what EF 4 lived in?