# Which version of Entity Framework is used by my project?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, version, entity-framework-5

I have a project using Entity Framework, but I am not sure which version of EF I am using. 
According to the [Microsoft version history](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj574253) EF5 will install itself:

> If you create a new model using the Entity Framework Designer in Visual Studio 2012, the EF5 NuGet package will be installed to your project and the generated code will make use of EF5.

However I did not create the EF-part of the project, but got it from version control (TFS).  Now I am not sure how to determine if I have EF5.

If I right-click on the References folder of the project and select Manage NuGet Packages, it show EF5 with an Uninstall-button, implying I have EF5.

But the system.data.entity in the References folder has a Runtime Version v4.0.30319 and Version 4.0.0.0 in the Properties explorer, which would imply EF 4 (according to [Determine version of Entity Framework I am using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377821/entity-framework-how-can-i-tell-what-version-i-am-using)).

I do have this in my `app.config`:

```
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```

And this in my `web.config`:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<!--...-->
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
<!--...-->
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
```

Can anybody clarify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12539749/422877) to [Entity Framework 5 not installing correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539742/entity-framework-5-not-installing-correctly), one should only look at `EntityFramework.dll`, which in my case shows **Runtime version**  v4.0.30319 but **Version** 5.0.0.0.  (So I do have EF 5.)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe your proyect is based in .NET 4.0, in this case you have an EF5 version without .NET 4.5 features:

[EntityFramework 5 use dll version 4.4.0.instead 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368304/entityframework-5-use-dll-version-4-4-0-instead-5-0)

Comment: Good point, which I hadn't thought of. I checked my projects, but they all seem to be .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 2):

Go to packages.config file of your project.

```
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same version number on System.Data.Entity. This comes from the .Net framework, not the Entity Framework installation. You can see which parts of your app are using it by right-clicking the reference and select **Find Code Dependent on Module**. There's generally not a lot unless the code is accessing metadata, mostly state enums and attribute defn's. Next version will bring all of this into the EntityFramework.dll - see [EFv6](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Updating%20Applications%20to%20use%20EF6)

BTW, looking at the folder in properties of System.Data.Entity, v4.0.30319 is in .NETFramework\v4.5

Comment: 1. Since I can not use features used by EF5, how is looking at the module-using code gonna help me?  2. According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12539749/422877), I should only be looking at `EntityFramework.dll`, which also shows **Runtime version** v4.0.30319 but **Version** 5.0.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get this kind of information is to install [Microsoft ASP.NET MVC Diagnostics 5.2.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcDiagnostics/)

This just produces a webpage for your project with all the pertinent information. For example, you could just search for "Entity" on that page and see the version information right away.

Here is an [article](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/05/asp-net-mvc-diagnostics-using-nuget.aspx/) showing one use of this diagnostic tool.